# Is it possible to avoid filesort?

Tags: mysql, performance, query-performance

Is it possible to avoid 'Using temporary' and 'Using filesort' for the following SELECT query? I can't figure out a way to do it.

[image]

I tried adding indexes, for both top_expire and program, but didn't help
With the ORDER BY the query takes over 1 second and withoud it is just 0.003 seconds on localhost

[image]

#### Query

```
SELECT ad.*, p.link
    FROM (SELECT ad.*
        FROM mod_ad ad 
        JOIN mod_ad_auta auta ON ad.id = auta.ad_id
        WHERE ad.active != 0 AND ad.usr_active != 0 AND ad.expire > 1371151608  AND ad.cat_id = '1' AND ad.price <= '10000' 
          AND auta.rocnik BETWEEN '1950' AND '2013' 
          AND auta.km BETWEEN '0' AND '500000'
        ORDER BY top_expire DESC, program DESC,  ad.id DESC  LIMIT 0,10) as ad
JOIN pages p ON ad.page_id=p.page_id;
```

#### Schema

```
CREATE TABLE `mod_ad` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `page_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `cat_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `subcat_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `program` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `region_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `zone_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `city_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `sort` enum('firm','priv') NOT NULL,
  `type` enum('predaj','kúpa','výmena','darujem','hľadám','ponúkam','iné') NOT NULL,
  `condition` varchar(24) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `desc` text NOT NULL,
  `location` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `keywords` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `price` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
  `price_type` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `cperson` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `firmname` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `zip` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `tel` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `tel2` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `web` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `video` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `marked_expire` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `top_expire` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `ad_hot_expire` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `ad_border_expire` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `ad_heading_expire` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `ad_weblink_expire` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `active` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `usr_active` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `added` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `archive` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `expire` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `token` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `views` mediumint(9) NOT NULL,
  `ip` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `user_id` (`user_id`),
  KEY `page_id` (`page_id`),
  KEY `cat_id` (`cat_id`),
  KEY `region_id` (`region_id`),
  KEY `zone_id` (`zone_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `mod_ad_auta` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ad_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `model` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `rocnik` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `palivo` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `karoseria` varchar(12) NOT NULL,
  `km` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `prevodovka` varchar(12) NOT NULL,
  `farba` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
  `metaliza` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `obsah` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `vykon` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `vybava` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `ad_id` (`ad_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: What version of MySQL?

Comment: On localhost 5.6.11, but on shared hosting it's going to be mysql-5.1.63-percona

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[The docs say](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/order-by-optimization.html)

> In some cases, MySQL cannot use indexes to resolve the ORDER BY,
>   although it still uses indexes to find the rows that match the WHERE
>   clause. These cases include the following:

and then go on to list many circumstances that prevent MySQL from using indexes. Among them are

> - You use ORDER BY on different keys
> - The key used to fetch the rows is not the same as the one used in the ORDER BY

and there are probably others.

To avoid a filesort, you have to find a way to get what you want without running into any of those (many) documented conditions.

You can also

> - Increase the size of the sort_buffer_size variable.
> - Increase the size of the read_rnd_buffer_size variable.
> - Use less RAM per row by declaring columns only as large as they need to be to hold the values stored in them.
> - Change tmpdir to point to a dedicated file system with large amounts of free space.

(Same link.)

Also see docs for [Optimizing LIMIT Queries](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/limit-optimization.html), which interacts with ORDER BY.

Comment: Thanks for explanation. I have added the ORDER BY field to the index and now it is not using filesort.